# Why I can't append a string to a empty list?

Tags: programming

Why I can't append a string to a empty list in Python? For example:

```
lista_arg= list()
arg="Nome"
lista_arg= lista_arg.append(arg)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solely about programming and not related to Quantitative Finance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question should be asked in StackOverflow. In any case:

`lista_arg.append(arg)` is a method that returns `None`

So you should use it just as:

`lista_arg.append(arg)`

and not:

`lista_arg = lista_arg.append(arg)`

because you are assigning `None` to your `lista_arg` variable...